# Accessing Properties in dynamically create objects within array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

I am trying to generate a deck of cards with 52 objects. I would like to put these objects in an array and be able to access the properties.  I succeeded in creating the objects and pushing them to an array.However, trying to access the properties from within the array returns 'undefined'.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for any help.

I have tried the following, and they are not working for me:

```
console.log(cards[0].displayName);
console.log(cards[0]['displayName']);
console.log(cards[0][displayName]);
```

I was also unsuccessful in accessing the properties via a 'for in' loop.

```
var cards = [];

function card(value, suit, image){
    this.value = value;
    this.displayName = value + ' of ' + suit;
    if (value == 1) this.displayName = 'Ace of ' +  suit;
    if (value ==  11) this.displayName = 'Jack of ' + suit;
    if (value ==  12) this.displayName = 'Queen of ' + suit;
    if (value ==  13) this.displayName = 'King of ' + suit;
    if (value >= 11) this.value = 10;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.image = image;
}

function generateDeck(){
    for (var i = 1; i <= 13; i++){
        window['Hearts' + i] = new card(i, 'Hearts');
        cards.push('Hearts' + i);
        window['Spades' + i] = new card(i, 'Spades');
        cards.push('Spades' + i);
        window['Clubs' + i] = new card(i, 'Clubs');
        cards.push('Clubs' + i);
        window['Diamonds' + i] = new card(i, 'Diamonds');
        cards.push('Diamonds' + i);                 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to push the `card` objects onto the Array:

```
function generateDeck(){
    for (var i = 1; i <= 13; i++){
        cards.push(
            new card(i, 'Hearts'),
            new card(i, 'Spades'),
            new card(i, 'Clubs'),
            new card(i, 'Diamonds')
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cards.push (variable)

You wrote cards.push ('hearts'+i);

so its a String addition with a Number which ends up in a String called hearts0 or hearts1 ..

which is saved under the array.

you dont save the card instance why do you wonder cards[0].displayName=undefined ??

try eval ("cards.push (hearts"+i+")");

but that would do nobody.

cards.push (windows ['hearts'+i]); but that would also do nobody why do you want globals